# How to pass a default value to an input in React (using props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, field

I have this Field that renders an Input component `RenderInput`. I need to pass a default value to it, something like `value="100"`.

```
      <Field
        name="hours"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Ingrese las horas para esta categoría"
        component={RenderInput}
        onChange={(event) => {
          handleSubmit(currentValues => this.debounceSubmitProduction({
            ...currentValues,
            hours: event.target.value,
          }))();
        }}
      />
```

This is the RenderInput component:

```
const RenderInput = ({
  input,
  type,
  disabled,
  readOnly,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  onKeyDown,
  innerRef,
}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      {...input}
      type={type}
      disabled={disabled}
      readOnly={readOnly}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={`font-300 ${touched && error && 'has-error'}`}
      onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      ref={innerRef}
    />
  </div>
);
```

If I put `value="100"` inside the RenderInput component, it works fine, but If I try to pass that value as a props to the RenderInput component, it doesn't work. How can I pass the property `value` from `<Field />` to RenderInput?

Answer (score 6):

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

> With an uncontrolled component, you often want React to specify the
>   initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle
>   this case, you can specify a `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`.

Comment: To piggyback on this answer: Only use the `defaultValue` attribute if you don't want the user to control the state of the input.  If they're going to be making changes to the input use the `value` attribute instead.  This will make the input controlled and will be updated via a `setState` function that you pass from your parent component to the Field component.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have several options and your question is wrong as default value is done via `defaultProps` but what you can do is

```
<Field
        name="hours"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Ingrese las horas para esta categoría"
        component={() => (<RenderInput input={{ value: 100 }}/> )}
        onChange={(event) => {
          handleSubmit(currentValues => this.debounceSubmitProduction({
            ...currentValues,
            hours: event.target.value,
          }))();
        }}
      />
```

please pay attention how it's destructured inside RenderInput

```
const RenderInput = ({
  input,
  type,
  disabled,
  readOnly,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  onKeyDown,
  innerRef,
}) => (
```

this means anything passed on `input` key will be destructured as prop to input, so if you need to send value you have to do `input={{value: 100}}` instead of `value=100` this prop is not destructured.

If you want to have default value, you can just add static to RenderInput

```
RenderInput.defaultProps = {
  input: { value: 100 }
}
```

**EDIT**

There is alsoclone function

```
const ComponentWithProps = React.CloneElement(RenderInput, { props })
```

or

Comment: I want the default value to be empty string, but when I pass the props with a default value, to show that value. I tried this but it didn't work :(

Comment: The error is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null`

Comment: You can setup default values on component with `static defaultProps = {}` and on stateless components (which you have on render input) same as I stated above, `RenderInput.defaultProps = {
  input: { value: 100 }
}` unless you will provide full example on https://stackblitz.com/ the uncaught error is probably unrelated to the question which you've asked

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Field
    name="hours"
    type="number"
    someValue='100'
    placeholder="Ingrese las horas para esta categoría"
    component={RenderInput}
    onChange={(event) => {
      handleSubmit(currentValues => this.debounceSubmitProduction({
        ...currentValues,
        hours: event.target.value,
      }))();
    }}
  />
```

Then

```
const RenderInput = ({
  input,
  type,
  disabled,
  readOnly,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  onKeyDown,
  innerRef,
  someValue
}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      {...input}
      type={type}
      disabled={disabled}
      readOnly={readOnly}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={`font-300 ${touched && error && 'has-error'}`}
      onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      ref={innerRef}
      defaultValue={someValue}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This is what I tried before, with `value` and with `defaultValue` but none of them worked :(

Comment: Well Did you get any error in console? as well answer updated

Comment: The errror is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null`